# an intelligent regex to convert links (from bbcode and not) in html

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm trying to create my own function for convert some links string from bbcode (and from normal string) to the right html.

At the moment I have this one :

```
$format_search=array(
    '#\[url=(((http|https|ftp)://)[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\./\?=&;\#]+)\](.*?)\[/url\]#i'
    '#(?<![>/"])(((http|https|ftp)://)[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\./\?=&;\#]+)#im',  
);

$format_replace=array(
  '<a class="lforum" href="$1">$4</a>',
  '<a class="lforum" href="$1">$1</a>',    
);

$str=preg_replace($format_search, $format_replace, $str);
```

it works more or less :)

Catching bbcode as [url=link]link_name[/url] is not a problem. The problem is when I try to catch every kind of link on the website. (for example when a user insert http://link.com without any bbcode).

For example [b]http://links[/b] doesnt work... and there are many others scenario to get in consideration!

I don't know how to create a good function without conflicts! I mean : first parse the string searching the link's strings as bbcode; than, parse the rest, maybe without replace the previous.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with that approach. The `(?<![>/"])` is what prevents it from working. The purpose of that assertion is to prevent double-linkifying `<a>http://example.com</a>`. But it also prevents matches on `<b>http://example.com`.

One workaround would be to alter your output links:

```
 '<a href="$1" class="lforum">$4</a>',
```

This would allow to use the class= in the negative assertion:

```
 (?<![/"]|class="lforum">)http..
```

So it still matches tags other than `<a>` links.

---

Another approach would be to pre-convert raw text URLs into BBcode before you convert your BBcode into HTML. Use your existing URL regex for that and prefix it with e.g. `(?<![\]=])` and use `[url=$1]$1[/url]` as output instead.

Comment: I think to have found a solution; is to convert first [url] and [img] bbcode tags. After, all links that doesnt start with " and finish with whitespace. Dunno how to do this, so check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936182/can-you-help-me-to-create-this-regex-for-parse-some-html-links, maybe you can help me :)