# How can I create my own regex for "parse" HTML links?

Tags: php, regex

The strings looks like hyperlinks, such as http://somethings. This is what I need :

1. I need to check them only if they doesnt start with the character `"`; I mean, only that characters : if before there aren't characters it must check;
2. That `somethings` string means that every kind of characters can be used (of course, is a link) except a whitespace (The end marker link); I know, it's permitted by RFC, but is the only way I know to escape;
3. these string are previously filtered by using `htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")`, that's why every kind of characters can be used. Is it secure? Or I risk problems with xss or html broked?
4. the occurences of this replacement can me multiple, not only 1, and must be case insenstive;

This is my actual regex :

```
preg_replace('#\b[^"](((http|https|ftp)://).+)#', '<a class="lforum" href="$1">$1</a>', $str);
```

But it check only those string that START with ", and I want the opposite. Any helps answering to this question would be good, Thanks!

Comment: 1 - you will need to split the words into individual strings. Then the regex would be `[^"].*`

Comment: [^"] should works, but if the word is the first word it doesnt (because before there isn't any characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Something like this: `preg_match('/\b[^"]/',$input_string);`

   This looks for a word-break (`\b`), followed by any character other than a double quote (`[^"]`).
2. Something like this: `preg_match('~(((ThisShouldBePresent)://).+)~');`

   I've assumed the brackets you specified in the question (and the plus sign) were intended as part of the regex rather than characters to search for.

   I've also taken @ThiefMaster's advice and changed the delimiter to `~` to avoid having to escape the `//`.

Comment: You might want to use a different delimiter for (2) so you don't have an escaping hell - `#` would do the job fine for example.

Comment: @Thief - but I *like* having to escape my slashes; it makes regex syntax even more obtuse! yay!  ;-) (but yes, I have edited it to use an alternative character)

Comment: Tried your example, but it doesnt work (maybe we misunderstand). I edited my topic with a more concise explanation ;)

Answer (score 2):

For both of your cases you'll want lookbehind assertions.

1. `\b(?<!")(\w)\b` - negative lookbehind to match only if not preceded by `"`
2. `(?<=ThisShouldBePresent://)(.*)` - positive lookbehind to match only if preceded by the your string.

Comment: Edited the topic with some others further infos (because this in fact doesnt work so well); Please let me know, thanks for your time